# How to stop over fitting a Model in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

I am working on Text Classification Problem. My Model looks like this :

```
Model: "sequential_6"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_6 (Embedding)      (None, 100, 50)           676050    
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_6 (LSTM)                (None, 16)                4288      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 16)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 51        
=================================================================
Total params: 680,389
Trainable params: 680,389
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

The dataset contains around 5300 No. of Sentences. I am using validation split=0.33.
The Model behaves in abnormal way. The validation loss keeps increasing and validation accuracy moves in constant way. I am attaching the graph. 
Please guide me how to solve this issue.

[image]

My Model looks like this :

```
    model=Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(
      num_words,
      EMBEDDING_DIM,
      input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH
    ))

model.add(LSTM(32,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(GlobalMaxPool1D())
model.add(Dense(len(possible_labels), activation="softmax"))
```

I am also attaching Accuracy Graph.[image]

Comment: This is not really abnormal at all. Models tend to overfit. 
Can you provide the full model of your network? I guess it does contain more than a single embedding, lstm, dropout and dense layer.

Comment: Could you please add the graph of the accuracy over the validation data?

Comment: Well, as you can see from your graph, your train loss approaches zero fast. So your train data is already well characterized by your model (almost 0 loss).

However, the val data is not. So, the graph more or less tells you that the model has learned everything it can and yet you continue to try to learn something that can not be learned/grasped by your model. 

Usually you stop training when the validation curve starts to rise. Or you change your model (train parameters or model structure). Difficult to give advice based on the data you've  given so far

Comment: @sheradil  : I have added model info.

Comment: @user3467955 : Added Accuracy graph.

Comment: The accuracy graph does not look like that I expected. It seems you already have an accuracy of 90%. Which seems to be quite good. If you want to get better results you might choose a more complex model, that is, a deeper one (more layers).

Answer (score 0):

1. Increase dropout.
2. Train for fewer epochs.
3. Try Conv1D instead of LSTM to see if the overfitting goes away.